# Toolbar Won't Show Menu Button

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I tried different methods of making a menu button on the Android Studio update but I couldn't make the menu button appear.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have added this code in the Activity and made a menu.xml file containing:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/expanded_menu"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_menu"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="button">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/credits"
        android:title="Credits"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        />
     <item android:title="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
         />
</menu>
```

Anyway, how I can make the three squares that were automatically added in the older versions of Android appear?

[image: App screenshot]

This is a screenshot of the application, in previous versions of android studio there were three dots at the top right corner.
Currently they are not there and my question is how do I add the menu button.

Edit: also while writing `app:showAsAction="always"` android studio marked all of the line red untill I wrote the "=" sign, maybe this error is related to something?
Also maybe I missed a step while making the items/toolbar, but I do not know exactly if I missed anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mainmenu, menu)` does what you want. What theme are you using? Do you have a even have a Toolbar?

Comment: I do, I added only a title to it and changed its color.
And I am using the Light theme  `app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light`

Comment: Try not making your toolbar black.

Comment: @cricket_007 changed it back to `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` and it still didn't show the menu button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the overflow button (labeled '3'):

[image]

This button appears when there is not enough room to display all of the items in your options menu, or when you designate specific items to not be shown as an action. This is handled by the [`app:showAsAction`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) attribute. There are five different values you can apply, which are described as follows:

> - **ifRoom** : Only place this item in the app bar if there is room for it. If there is not room for all the items marked `"ifRoom"`, the
>     items with the lowest `orderInCategory` values are displayed as
>     actions, and the remaining items are displayed in the overflow menu.
> - **withText** : Also include the title text (defined by `android:title`) with the action item. You can include this value
>     along with one of the others as a flag set, by separating them with a
>     pipe `|`.
> - **never** : Never place this item in the app bar. Instead, list the item in the app bar's overflow menu.
> - **always** : Always place this item in the app bar. Avoid using this unless it's critical that the item always appear in the action
>     bar. Setting multiple items to always appear as action items can
>     result in them overlapping with other UI in the app bar.
> - **collapseActionView** : The action view associated with this action item (as declared by `android:actionLayout` or
>     `android:actionViewClass`) is collapsible. Introduced in API Level 14.

Therefore, if you want to *only* show the overflow button, you should set `app:showAsAction="never"` for all of your menu items.

Though, the typical structure for an options menu is to always show the first item, and designate the rest to be shown `"ifRoom"`.

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the problem. The menu clearly has an `always` item, but there is nothing displayed in the image.

Comment: As you can see in the picture, there are no items on the toolbar even though I made them in the menu file.

Comment: @cricket_007 You are correct, I didn't see the edit adding the image before I posted.

Comment: I can try to run an app that has the items and compare the apps if someone can send me a simple app

Comment: @DanStre I think I may know what you are missing… are you using an `AppCompatActivity`? Is there a `Toolbar` in the layout of your `Activity`? And what is your App Theme?

Comment: Actually I found the problem, I had a miss match of IDs in the java file, the tollbar's name was my_toolbar but because I copied the code from the internet it was written only toolbar in the `findviewbyid`